# How to check if a cell is empty in an excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel

Trying to check if cell value in excel is empty.
If it is empty i want to write The value of a close cell (for example, A25 is empty. I want B25 value).
And I want to go through the whole excel file.
Here's my code for now and im stuck! (scroll to the bottom of the code. The last part is important).

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnReadExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + txtFileName.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0");


            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from[Sheet1$]", con);
            da.Fill(dsContacts);
            MessageBox.Show(dsContacts.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString());
            dgContacts.DataSource = dsContacts.Tables[0];


        }

        private void tblContactsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tblContactsBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.database11DataSet);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.tblContactsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database11DataSet.tblContacts);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                    foreach (DataRow r in dsContacts.Tables[0].Rows) 
                     {

                       DataRow dr = database11DataSet.tblContacts.NewRow();
                        dr[0] = r[0];
                        dr[1] = r[1];
                        dr[2] = r[2];
                        database11DataSet.tblContacts.Rows.Add(dr);
                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain in your own words the logic to determine a "close" cell?

Comment: I can give an example:
Cell B25 is empty. I would like to get the value of cell C25.

Comment: So does an empty cell always look to the right?  A -> B -> C -> etc?  What do you want to happen if B & C are empty, but A is not?  Or is that not a possibility?

Comment: Ok i will make it as simple as i can.
I want to check only the A row.
If it is empty I want to print B. (again, If A25 is empty, print B25)
Nothing further..
Only A can be empty. B will always have a value.